# But I don't think I want to buy any shirts and pants after all

Tags: phrases

At a clothing store

---

**Store Keeper**: Put it on, will you?

**Boy**: Oh, but I can't. It's too small. It doesn't fit.
Is this the largest size you have?

**Store Keeper**: This is a large.

**Boy**: Oh, oh, it doesn't matter. There are lots of clothes I want to buy.

.

.

.

**Store Keeper**: Ah, ah, ah. Decide what you want, and then I'll come back. I'm very busy, you know.

**Boy**: But I don't think I want to buy any shirts and pants **after all**.

**Store Keeper**: And why not?

**Boy**: Because it's too difficult to choose. I can't make up my mind.

---

What does "**after all**" mean in this dialogue?

Does it mean "**nevertheless**"?

Comment: **warning unnatural dialogue**, "After all" is a phrase that can be found in the dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/after-all  Note the way the shopkeeper and the boy talk is very artificial.  I can't imagine a shopkeeper ordering someone to put on something that is too small, the use of "any shirts and pants"  is odd The reason "Its to difficult to choose" doesn't match the conclusion "I don't want to buy". The whole thing is wrong.  Please tell me why you continue to use this resource?

Comment: "I don't want to buy any shirts and pants" is also strange. The opposite of "I do this and that" is "I **don't** do this **or** that". (If you are familiar with mathematics, you might compare it to De Morgan's Law)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevertheless and after all do have similar meanings, but they are used in different ways.

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nevertheless), nevertheless is use to say "despite what has just been **said or referred to**". Note that it relates to something that has just been mentioned in the conversation.

The Cambridge Dictionary definition is not so helpful for **after all**: since it only refers to things that go ahead, when it can also be used about things that don't go ahead, as in this situation. I would define it as "despite things that **have happened in the past**", so it is used to refer to things that have happened rather than things that have been mentioned.

In this case, the boy was initially keen to buy clothes, but changed his mind: this is something that happened, rather than something that was mentioned, so only **after all** can be used.

---

As James K pointed out, this is not a very realistic conversation for two native English speakers: it has the air of something that might be said in another language, that has then been translated into English by a non-native speaker. "Oh, Oh" and "Ah, Ah, Ah" are definitely unnatural, and the boy would say "There are lots of **other** clothes I want to buy".